# C#/WPF Movable TabItems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabs, drag-and-drop

I want to create movable TabItems. But when I drop the Item, it crashes because of index was out of array area.

Please tell me about my mistakes
Code:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
```

Code Behind:

```
 private void TabItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = e.Source as TabItem;

        if (tabItem == null)
            return;

        if (Mouse.PrimaryDevice.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tabItem, tabItem, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
    }


    private void TabItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItemTarget = e.Source as TabItem;

        var tabItemSource = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabItem)) as TabItem;

        if (!tabItemTarget.Equals(tabItemSource))
        {
            var tabControl = tabItemTarget.Parent as TabControl;
            int sourceIndex = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tabItemSource);
            int targetIndex = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tabItemTarget);

            tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItemSource);
            tabControl.Items.Insert(targetIndex, tabItemSource);

            tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItemTarget);
            tabControl.Items.Insert(sourceIndex, tabItemTarget);
        }
    }
```

//EDIT:
My SelectionChanged Event let the program crash. But I need it because otherwise my whole program wouldn't work. The reason of the crash is that I use the SelectedIndex value of the TabControl, which is undefined in that moment

Comment: is it all you have? your sample works on my side without any exceptions

Comment: How about showing us the `SelectionChanged` event handler that is the reason of the crash?